# How to keep the background color of UICollectionViewCells from changing when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My `UICollectionView`'s cells have a `contentview` with a background color of white upon loading.  Users can change the background color of the cell's `contentview` to cyan by selecting the cell assuming a boolean value `(isSplitting)` is set to `YES`.

[image]

My problem arises when I have more cells then fit on the screen and the user has selected cells and thus changed their contentview's background color to cyan.

I have instances where cells that are cyan get scrolled out of view and when scrolled back in are white.  I also have instances where cells that are not cyan are scrolled into view and are cyan.

I understand that the cells are being dequeued for reuse and retaining their background colors when getting loaded into a different `indexpath`.

I have resolved the issues of cells that are not selected becoming cyan upon scrolling into view.  I have not however been able to resolve the issue of certain selected cells losing their cyan color when scrolled in and out of view.

Here is the current logic I have in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

```
if (!isSplitting) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else{
        for (NSIndexPath *collectionIndexPath in [self.myCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]) {
            if (indexPath == collectionIndexPath) {
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
                break;
            }
            else{
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }
        }
    }
```

I know the that correct cells are indeed selected because another operation using the same for loop above produces the desired results.  The logic seems to breakdown if I select the first couple items (turn them to cyan), scroll to the right and select the 10th item.  When I scroll back to the left the first couple are still cyan but upon scrolling to the right again the 10th is back to white.

Comment: What is the logic behind isSplitting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isEqual: to compare the indexPaths rather than ==

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:collectionIndexPath]) {
```